# Easiest way to recursively find and replace?

Tags: grep, replace

I want to recursively search through a directory of text files and replace every occurrence of `foo` within the files with `bar`.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

I imagine that grep would do the job in one line, but I can't seem to find an example of this.

I'm working in OS X.

Comment: Are you talking about **foo** in the names of files or foo within the files themselves?

Comment: Sorry, clarified.  Within files please.

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GNU find

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.txt" -exec sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/g' "{}" +;
```

Comment: for Mac OS use `$ find ./UnitTests/ -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sed -i '' -e 's/foo/bar/g' {} +`

Answer (score 3):

`grep` is only used to *find* things, not to modify them.

For modifications with a grep-like interface, you'd typically use `sed`. By itself, `sed` doesn't support any kind of recursion though -- it only operates on one file at a time. To add that, you normally use `find` to find the files to contain the desired pattern, then have it invoke `sed` to modify the file.

Answer (score 2):

zsh

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' **/*.txt
```

Comment: how to scape '/' if foo and bar are paths?

Comment: @rraallvv with \, of course. Or use some other delimiter instead of `/` in the `s` command.

Answer (score 2):

try this:
`grep -rl "foo" .|xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'`

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice free text editor that will do this kind of thing simply and easily: [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Comment: Cool. How do I install it on my server?

Comment: Assuming it's an OS X server then just download and install in the normal way. If it's headless then use VNC or Remote Desktop. Of course you may not even need to install it on the server - if you're using an OS X machine locally and mounting file systems from your server then you can just install TextWrangler locally and do the search and replace from your local machine over the network.